# Magento 2 : Indexing for large database is taking so much time

Tags: indexer, magento-2.1.8

I have imported more than **250000 of products** for **two stores**. I am trying to **indexing** those products but it is taking long time through **SSH**.Indexing Taking **so much time** and then after **indexer lock**. If I **reset indexing** using below command , then also not working.

`php -f magento indexer:reset`

Is there is any way that i can perform indexing on those products ?

**Magento 2.1.8**

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Facing the same issue right now with version 2.2.1. There is a fix for 2.1.8 that makes the indexer quite faster in this github issue [#10531](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/10531#issuecomment-330832822).
Yet to try this on 2.2.1, I'll update you once I try it out. Note that the issue is closed but does not seem to be fixed. I just now finished indexing the catalog_product_price index and it took an insane 43h57m for ~350K products.

As mentioned in the previous link by *@ashuston*, you can change the return value to `false` for the method `isRangingNeeded()` in the `Catalog/Model/Indexer/Category/Product/AbstractAction` class. That should make the indexing process faster but still pretty long.

Now, to answer your question, here are the steps to run the indexers :

`php ./bin/magento indexer:status` - will tell you what indexers need to be ran
`php ./bin/magento indexer:info` - find the names of the indexers *(catalog_product_category)*
`php ./bin/magento indexer:reindex name_of_the_index` - will run only the specified index. If no index name is specified it will reindex all (might take a while...)

So far this is the only way to manually run indexers on Magento 2. The other way consists of creating cron jobs and running them on a schedule.